# Httplistener get request through localhost, Not through Network ip address

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to call my httplistener service through ajax jquery, it gets response on localhost, but not getting response through network ip.

This is how I am trying to test on jquery:

```
function getSuccessOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:90', //'http://192.168.1.1:90'
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#output').html(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#output').html('there was an error!');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

My httplistener code in c#:

```
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add(string.Format("http://" + item.ToString() + ":{0}/", port));
httpListener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
httpListener.Start();
while (true)
{
   HttpListenerContext context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
   HttpListenerRequest req = context.Request;
```

I have doubt it could be AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous and trying to check on AuthenticationSchemes for httplistener, but unable to find out reason.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting error, blank response on network ip and getting response as 'Server is running' on localhost

Comment: and what do you see if you open dev tools in your browser, network section?

Comment: localhost & network ip both responding properly on browser as '<RESPONSE>Server is Running</RESPONSE>', dont understand why its not responding through jquery for network ip, local ip getting response on browser & jquery properly.

Comment: What is item and its value?

Comment: function getFailOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://192.168.1.2:90',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data, response);
            $('#output').html(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#output').html('Connection error!');
        },
    });
    return false;
}

If I try to test with above jquery, I am getting error as mentioned in code, i.e. 'Connection error!'

Comment: item value I am using sometime as * or 192.168.1.2/127.0.0.1, picking from listbox

Comment: ajax "error" handler provides more info in arguments, which you ignore. "Connection error!" (which is the message you created yourself) doesn't give us any info about that error.

Comment: I can see the ip in the question is 192.168.1.1, but in your comment it's 192.168.1.2, I think you should check this up.

Comment: 1.1 was typing mistake, its 1.2, i checked network ip, thats not the problem

Comment: @Evk  are you asking about this error > jqXHR.status === 0 or please guide me